# Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "sass"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, gemfile, gemfile.lock

I am using middleman 3.3.9 and

```
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.1'
gem 'bootstrap-timepicker-rails'
gem 'sass', '~> 3.2.19'
```

When I run bundle install, I get this error:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "sass":
      In Gemfile:
        middleman (~> 3.3.9) ruby depends on
          sass (< 4.0, >= 3.4.0) ruby

        sass (3.2.19)
```

How can I make this pass?

Comment: It is failing because you have added `gem 'sass', '~> 3.2.19'` in Gemfile explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're having a dependent gem conflict problem. You've locked `sass-rails` down so it can't bring in a `sass` that's new enough to satisfy the version of `middleman` that you're running.

You need to either lower the version of `middleman` that you're using, or increase the version of `sass-rails`.

Comment: Heh, no problem. Once you know how to read the errors, they're actually very informative. Keep at it, these problems trip everyone over at some point :)

Answer (score 2):

update Gemfile with the following line.

`gem 'sass', '~> 3.4.0'`

**Edit**

basically you'll need to upgrade all `sass` dependant gems to a level, every dependant gem uses same version of `sass`

Comment: tried that before and I get another error: Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "sass":
  In Gemfile:
    sass-rails (~> 4.0.3) ruby depends on
      sass (~> 3.2.0) ruby

    sass (3.4.0)

Comment: try removing `sass` from Gemfile

Comment: same error. maybe removing Gemfile.lock and bundle again?

Comment: basically you'll need to upgrade all `sass` dependant gems to a level, every dependant gem uses same version of `sass`.